# Return nested JSON from Models with relations in Django

Tags: json, django, serialization

**models.py (simplified)**

```py
class Author(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_books(self):
        return Book.objects.filter(author=self.pk)


class Book(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    pages = models.IntegerField()
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.name} from {self.author}'


class Paragraph(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    book = models.ForeignKey(Book, on_delete=models.CASCADE)


    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.name} from {self.book}'
```

I want to return all the instances in a json file with this structure:

```json
[
    {
        "name": 'Dumas', 
        "books": {
            "name": "The count of Montecristo",
            "paragraphs": {
                "name": "paragraph_name_1",
                         },
                          {
                "name": "paragraph_name_2",
                         },
                 {
            "name": "The three Musketeers",
            "paragraphs": {
                "name": "paragraph_name",
                         },
]
```

**What I tried:**
**serializers.py**

```py
class AuthorSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    books = serializers.CharField(source='get_books', read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Author
        fields = ['name', 'books']
```

This add the `books` key but the value is the string representation of the istances of `Book` (of course), how I make the value being the serialized istances of `Book`? I have created a `BookSerializer`.
**Notes:**
I know that I can created a nested json by creating a serializer for `Paragraph` with `depth = 2` but this will include fields I don't want (like `pages` in `Book`) and the json structure will be totally different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create *nested serializer* as

```
class ParagraphSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Paragraph
        fields = ("name",)


class BookSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    paragraphs = ParagraphSerializer(source="paragraph_set", many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Book
        fields = ("name", "paragraphs")


class AuthorSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    books = BookSerializer(source="book_set", read_only=True, many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Author
        fields = ['name', 'books']
```

Comment: This works out perfectly but I don't understand the origin of source="paragraph_set", I cannot find it in the rest framework docs, can you explain or link the doc that references it? Thank you I appreciate.

Comment: Here is the ref to the DRF [`source`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#source) @JLeno46